# Sizing table with tablesorter and jquery layout

Tags: tablesorter, jquery-layout

I'd like to use a tablesorter table inside the main (center) panel of a jquery layout panel. The width of the table works fine but getting the table to occupy the available height is not so obvious.

I have a basic example working below based on some trial and error, this is based on setting the max-height property of the tablesorter-scroller-table. It *kind of* works but gives unpredictable results; sometimes the table height is exactly that of the allowable height and sometimes there's a margin of up to 100 or so pixels.

Is there a more reliable and elegant way to tell the table to occupy the available vertical space?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
      -- Based on scroller widget demo at
      -- http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-scroller.html
      --
      -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Scroller Widget Test</title>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="js/docs.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-layout.js"></script>

    <script src="tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script src="tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="tablesorter/js/widgets/widget-scroller.min.js"></script>

    <link class="ui-theme" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jq.css">
    <link href="css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/layout-default-latest.css" rel="stylesheet">    

    <link class="theme blue" rel="stylesheet" href="tablesorter/css/theme.blue.min.css">

    <style id="css">
    #fixed-columns-table tbody td {
        /* force "Notes" column to not wrap, so we get a horizontal scrolling demo! (optional css) */
        white-space: nowrap;
        /* Add min column width, or "Index" column filter gets too narrow to use (optional css) */
        min-width: 60px;        
    }
    </style>

    <script id="js">
    $(function(){
        $('#fixed-columns-table').tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            widgets: ['scroller', 'zebra'],
            widgetOptions : {
                scroller_height : 200,
                scroller_fixedColumns : 2
            }
        });

        $('body').layout({
            applyDefaultStyles: false,
            north: {
                resizable: false
            },
            south: {
                resizable: false
            }
        });

        adjustHeight();
    });

    function adjustHeight() {       
        var h = $("#mainAppArea").height();
        var heightOffset = 150; // Trial and error
        var newHeight = parseInt(h)-heightOffset; 

        $(".tablesorter-scroller-table").css({
            height: '',
            'max-height': newHeight + 'px'
        });

        $("#feedback").text("Got app height: " + h + ", set max-height to " + newHeight + "px");
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onresize="adjustHeight()">

        <div class="ui-layout-north no-print">
            The Header
        </div>

        <div class="ui-layout-west no-print" style="padding: 0;">
            The side menu
        </div>

        <div class="ui-layout-center" id="mainAppArea" style="overflow: hidden;">

                <table id="fixed-columns-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Index</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Zip</th>
                            <th>Telephone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Notes</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Index</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Zip</th>
                            <th>Telephone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Notes</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>1</td><td>Sherry</td><td>Mills</td><td>223</td><td>3792 Sit Rd</td><td>NE</td><td>69836</td><td>(627) 124-8760</td><td>DRamirez@massa.ly</td><td>sagittis amet mattis facilisis vitae molestie nec dolor id sed</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>2</td><td>Markella</td><td>Lessenberry</td><td>895</td><td>5979 Sit Ln</td><td>VA</td><td>97761</td><td>(768) 233-5399</td><td>SPeltier@pulvinar.net</td><td>elementum nullam lacus elit magna libero sed dolor pulvinar orci</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>3</td><td>Lee</td><td>Trenkelbach</td><td>719</td><td>5656 Adipiscing Ave</td><td>ID</td><td>30972</td><td>(149) 293-0691</td><td>LSheppard@lectus.net</td><td>vestibulum at rutrum molestie convallis vestibulum nec egestas consequat vitae</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>4</td><td>Sherrye</td><td>Llc</td><td>908</td><td>2348 Pharetra St</td><td>UT</td><td>50740</td><td>(772) 682-4268</td><td>MAltar@turpis.io</td><td>sit elit consequat amet elit consectetur vestibulum vel quis consequat</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>5</td><td>Juanito</td><td>Lindall</td><td>534</td><td>5181 Lacus Ln</td><td>ID</td><td>71689</td><td>(528) 174-6999</td><td>CKeen@augue.ly</td><td>dui porttitor vestibulum mattis ipsum nunc et morbi dolor ipsum</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>6</td><td>Andre</td><td>Fuller</td><td>716</td><td>8224 Pulvinar Ave</td><td>WY</td><td>12382</td><td>(654) 593-0007</td><td>AMelvin@sed.net</td><td>dolor curabitur nec molestie lacus odio id velit sed neque</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>7</td><td>Sajid</td><td>Cattanach</td><td>997</td><td>3762 Ac Rd</td><td>WA</td><td>16719</td><td>(425) 909-2771</td><td>BMaas@ac.org</td><td>morbi tincidunt ac sollicitudin nec ac orci vitae donec non</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>8</td><td>Heidi</td><td>Rush</td><td>738</td><td>1425 Porta Rd</td><td>SD</td><td>14708</td><td>(341) 095-7183</td><td>DSchrag@sapien.net</td><td>nullam sed aliquam turpis et sagittis libero sed tellus dui</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>9</td><td>Ganesh</td><td>Comeau</td><td>385</td><td>2641 Hendrerit Dr</td><td>MT</td><td>66612</td><td>(201) 977-9765</td><td>SBurks@ipsum.ly</td><td>sit vestibulum ac pretium eget augue sit augue sagittis tellus</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>10</td><td>Regine</td><td>Marina</td><td>479</td><td>6204 Ac Rd</td><td>WI</td><td>55667</td><td>(824) 223-9924</td><td>VPeschke@pharetra.org</td><td>amet fringilla vitae tortor vestibulum egestas eget eget amet sed</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>11</td><td>Wichaya</td><td>Thomas</td><td>487</td><td>861 Risus Dr</td><td>KY</td><td>63224</td><td>(599) 823-8970</td><td>BMohamed@adipiscing.ly</td><td>placerat dolor pulvinar nec morbi amet porta sagittis lacus magna</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>12</td><td>Douglass</td><td>Holliday</td><td>488</td><td>8829 Sit Ave</td><td>IA</td><td>86970</td><td>(113) 897-8276</td><td>CLieb@convallis.io</td><td>dolor magna id amet lorem eros ipsum magna non aliquam</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>13</td><td>Prince</td><td>Schwartzberg</td><td>790</td><td>1757 Sit Ct</td><td>IL</td><td>94739</td><td>(299) 471-3039</td><td>DFavus@quis.org</td><td>magna tincidunt ipsum hendrerit ac vitae tortor consequat magna elit</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>14</td><td>Lola</td><td>Hensley</td><td>486</td><td>8159 Dui Rd</td><td>MN</td><td>88877</td><td>(788) 031-7392</td><td>MBradley@scelerisque.org</td><td>suspendisse donec placerat nec suspendisse lacus ipsum elementum at lorem</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>15</td><td>Dainius</td><td>Finn</td><td>355</td><td>6072 Massa Dr</td><td>VT</td><td>75787</td><td>(638) 345-2650</td><td>MWilcox@velit.ly</td><td>morbi pretium dui dolor elit sed non vestibulum sit dui</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>16</td><td>Aisha</td><td>Schuhmann</td><td>328</td><td>9709 Sagittis Ln</td><td>ND</td><td>44161</td><td>(147) 281-5251</td><td>GDech@mi.com</td><td>massa sed placerat libero egestas at massa sagittis libero orci</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>17</td><td>Maria</td><td>Peacock</td><td>269</td><td>2241 Amet Ave</td><td>MO</td><td>81339</td><td>(656) 079-5964</td><td>POliva@tincidunt.org</td><td>ac hendrerit molestie ipsum facilisis massa odio fringilla hendrerit neque</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>18</td><td>Otilia</td><td>Denbesten</td><td>778</td><td>1965 Nunc Ct</td><td>SC</td><td>98692</td><td>(985) 745-0452</td><td>SWieber@porttitor.net</td><td>aliquam orci odio id ac magna magna aenean sagittis lectus</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>19</td><td>Jian</td><td>Sanchez</td><td>796</td><td>6439 Sit Ln</td><td>OR</td><td>24879</td><td>(168) 754-6725</td><td>AVrtis@porttitor.net</td><td>sapien ipsum nullam pretium quis tincidunt tincidunt sit mattis porttitor</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>20</td><td>Tanny</td><td>Wieland</td><td>814</td><td>7331 Et Rd</td><td>SD</td><td>65216</td><td>(414) 322-1606</td><td>ACasariego@et.org</td><td>odio augue in id lacus tincidunt morbi tempor orci tincidunt</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>21</td><td>Alejandro</td><td>Sidaway</td><td>995</td><td>8125 Placerat Rd</td><td>VA</td><td>98301</td><td>(202) 112-1194</td><td>RHaag@nullam.ly</td><td>lacus aliquam et sagittis etiam aenean lorem ipsum non facilisis</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>22</td><td>Yolanda</td><td>Swanson</td><td>530</td><td>276 Amet Ct</td><td>VT</td><td>42999</td><td>(621) 796-4436</td><td>TDenard@lectus.gov</td><td>lacus vitae quis dui orci ipsum odio pulvinar et nunc</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>23</td><td>Azra</td><td>Filleul</td><td>443</td><td>499 Sagittis Dr</td><td>OK</td><td>59700</td><td>(485) 530-0532</td><td>LSwetland@consectetur.net</td><td>magna mattis sollicitudin placerat vel facilisis sed ac non et</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>24</td><td>Cassandra</td><td>Labrucherie</td><td>606</td><td>6849 Tellus Ct</td><td>SC</td><td>44245</td><td>(960) 044-9381</td><td>WLafave@lectus.io</td><td>ac nullam magna ante sapien tellus tincidunt eros magna sagittis</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>25</td><td>Theodore</td><td>Saver</td><td>150</td><td>5 Tincidunt Ave</td><td>IL</td><td>58210</td><td>(152) 001-4978</td><td>KTorres@sed.io</td><td>ac tincidunt nec rutrum pulvinar id aliquam placerat pharetra placerat</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>26</td><td>Susi</td><td>Murphy</td><td>900</td><td>1614 Hendrerit St</td><td>AZ</td><td>80212</td><td>(532) 030-5050</td><td>ZRingling@sit.io</td><td>quis odio et sapien sit amet eros et augue turpis</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>27</td><td>Corazon</td><td>Lawrence</td><td>577</td><td>3571 Facilisis Rd</td><td>CA</td><td>35195</td><td>(318) 200-2692</td><td>REckhart@scelerisque.io</td><td>tincidunt sit dolor mi donec magna massa vel suspendisse placerat</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>28</td><td>Khosrow</td><td>Fisher</td><td>802</td><td>4323 Tortor Ln</td><td>AK</td><td>38949</td><td>(493) 277-9670</td><td>FHarmati@magna.ly</td><td>lectus tortor ac ipsum sagittis lacus dolor ac fringilla nec</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>29</td><td>Melgema</td><td>Lopez</td><td>893</td><td>1738 Vestibulum Ln</td><td>MS</td><td>32638</td><td>(953) 255-2707</td><td>ABurgin@tortor.ly</td><td>molestie at vel at placerat pharetra consequat dolor nunc placerat</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>30</td><td>Chun</td><td>Lester</td><td>928</td><td>9681 Vestibulum Ct</td><td>ND</td><td>21333</td><td>(474) 719-0476</td><td>ETierney@pulvinar.gov</td><td>vestibulum ipsum tincidunt placerat eros turpis morbi ipsum sit malesuada</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>31</td><td>Dwayne</td><td>Balasubramanian</td><td>418</td><td>3129 Pharetra Dr</td><td>SD</td><td>57558</td><td>(457) 589-4620</td><td>ESyner@aenean.com</td><td>amet sit nec amet lectus augue consequat consectetur vel sed</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>32</td><td>Joshua</td><td>Williamson</td><td>702</td><td>6313 Vestibulum St</td><td>NJ</td><td>39057</td><td>(346) 084-7444</td><td>VFeldman@elit.ly</td><td>sit tempor at lacus libero lorem sit nullam tempor aliquam</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>33</td><td>Shawn</td><td>Dartmann</td><td>124</td><td>4892 Aliquam Rd</td><td>IA</td><td>17745</td><td>(500) 390-3779</td><td>RNesbitt@massa.net</td><td>sit sapien magna libero augue consectetur fringilla orci ac tortor</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>34</td><td>Rupa</td><td>Helgren</td><td>594</td><td>5944 Sed Ave</td><td>CO</td><td>96680</td><td>(174) 841-4348</td><td>FShebish@morbi.net</td><td>at elementum neque ac in consequat elementum magna vitae mattis</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>35</td><td>Gia</td><td>Marks</td><td>635</td><td>2519 Convallis Dr</td><td>GA</td><td>66324</td><td>(188) 657-9140</td><td>SForsyth@adipiscing.gov</td><td>pharetra pulvinar amet dui elementum suspendisse et odio tellus amet</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>36</td><td>Tyetha</td><td>Ahn</td><td>543</td><td>9900 Eros Ct</td><td>PA</td><td>53390</td><td>(482) 686-6141</td><td>LHobbs@non.io</td><td>pulvinar lorem quis fringilla eget velit sed augue rutrum augue</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>37</td><td>Gregory</td><td>Christine</td><td>527</td><td>751 Ipsum Rd</td><td>AK</td><td>44543</td><td>(258) 666-2073</td><td>HCrooker@donec.com</td><td>massa vitae dolor sollicitudin consectetur sollicitudin malesuada massa velit egestas</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>38</td><td>Yelena</td><td>Shanoski</td><td>646</td><td>1612 Donec Ave</td><td>KY</td><td>30729</td><td>(905) 301-3407</td><td>JMcmenamin@massa.gov</td><td>sapien rutrum adipiscing et sed sollicitudin vestibulum pharetra at neque</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>39</td><td>Thursday</td><td>Helm</td><td>666</td><td>5568 Nec Rd</td><td>NE</td><td>94390</td><td>(487) 403-7019</td><td>RMorin@sed.org</td><td>risus hendrerit sollicitudin vestibulum placerat lorem eros consequat lorem magna</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>40</td><td>Melinda</td><td>Oliva</td><td>525</td><td>6973 Rutrum Ct</td><td>IA</td><td>38519</td><td>(964) 234-5172</td><td>FStephens@in.com</td><td>dolor lacus nec odio in etiam facilisis lorem ipsum et</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>41</td><td>Latasha</td><td>Slocum</td><td>210</td><td>8374 Fringilla St</td><td>NV</td><td>23913</td><td>(678) 453-4263</td><td>JWelchert@id.gov</td><td>donec massa dolor elementum scelerisque risus lacus id lorem in</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>42</td><td>Kenneth</td><td>Zazzara</td><td>269</td><td>3364 Tempor Dr</td><td>MO</td><td>30642</td><td>(874) 633-3017</td><td>TGarayan@tincidunt.ly</td><td>sollicitudin nullam egestas aenean molestie velit nec sed tincidunt scelerisque</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>43</td><td>Francine</td><td>Daniels</td><td>366</td><td>2141 Amet Rd</td><td>OH</td><td>90786</td><td>(856) 781-7309</td><td>SIngham@pretium.ly</td><td>egestas amet vel ac pretium lacus nec tortor facilisis et</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>44</td><td>Marie</td><td>Krebs</td><td>124</td><td>4229 Sit Ln</td><td>DE</td><td>41786</td><td>(572) 023-1295</td><td>EClagg@curabitur.io</td><td>lacus elit sagittis quis nec vestibulum malesuada mattis morbi etiam</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>45</td><td>Stanley</td><td>Zehnacker</td><td>456</td><td>4610 Odio St</td><td>VT</td><td>70223</td><td>(257) 234-6755</td><td>HPennell@morbi.gov</td><td>vel aliquam mattis libero sed pharetra donec malesuada pharetra lectus</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>46</td><td>Furdella</td><td>Toffoli</td><td>951</td><td>8366 Placerat Rd</td><td>AZ</td><td>20381</td><td>(740) 422-8726</td><td>YEarls@morbi.net</td><td>non aliquam neque tortor egestas pulvinar tempor amet molestie lorem</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>47</td><td>Talatha</td><td>Nye</td><td>808</td><td>6884 Dolor Dr</td><td>MS</td><td>97282</td><td>(589) 157-7730</td><td>DAcosta@rutrum.gov</td><td>ipsum turpis vestibulum at convallis sit neque elementum sed adipiscing</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>48</td><td>Brent</td><td>Vollrath</td><td>479</td><td>5362 Eget Dr</td><td>MO</td><td>74989</td><td>(664) 642-4525</td><td>YMarina@sollicitudin.net</td><td>massa elementum elit pretium malesuada mi vestibulum non aliquam neque</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>49</td><td>Melissa</td><td>Quintana</td><td>405</td><td>1302 Lacus Dr</td><td>PA</td><td>38853</td><td>(354) 903-9363</td><td>AMarrinson@lacus.io</td><td>morbi quis neque placerat malesuada tincidunt morbi risus at tortor</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>50</td><td>Guadalupe</td><td>Eseltine</td><td>206</td><td>5495 Rutrum Ct</td><td>AR</td><td>37546</td><td>(540) 500-5816</td><td>TLester@morbi.com</td><td>porttitor sit massa ipsum ac massa ac hendrerit vitae malesuada</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>1</td><td>Sherry</td><td>Mills</td><td>223</td><td>3792 Sit Rd</td><td>NE</td><td>69836</td><td>(627) 124-8760</td><td>DRamirez@massa.ly</td><td>sagittis amet mattis facilisis vitae molestie nec dolor id sed</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>2</td><td>Markella</td><td>Lessenberry</td><td>895</td><td>5979 Sit Ln</td><td>VA</td><td>97761</td><td>(768) 233-5399</td><td>SPeltier@pulvinar.net</td><td>elementum nullam lacus elit magna libero sed dolor pulvinar orci</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>3</td><td>Lee</td><td>Trenkelbach</td><td>719</td><td>5656 Adipiscing Ave</td><td>ID</td><td>30972</td><td>(149) 293-0691</td><td>LSheppard@lectus.net</td><td>vestibulum at rutrum molestie convallis vestibulum nec egestas consequat vitae</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>4</td><td>Sherrye</td><td>Llc</td><td>908</td><td>2348 Pharetra St</td><td>UT</td><td>50740</td><td>(772) 682-4268</td><td>MAltar@turpis.io</td><td>sit elit consequat amet elit consectetur vestibulum vel quis consequat</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>5</td><td>Juanito</td><td>Lindall</td><td>534</td><td>5181 Lacus Ln</td><td>ID</td><td>71689</td><td>(528) 174-6999</td><td>CKeen@augue.ly</td><td>dui porttitor vestibulum mattis ipsum nunc et morbi dolor ipsum</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>6</td><td>Andre</td><td>Fuller</td><td>716</td><td>8224 Pulvinar Ave</td><td>WY</td><td>12382</td><td>(654) 593-0007</td><td>AMelvin@sed.net</td><td>dolor curabitur nec molestie lacus odio id velit sed neque</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>7</td><td>Sajid</td><td>Cattanach</td><td>997</td><td>3762 Ac Rd</td><td>WA</td><td>16719</td><td>(425) 909-2771</td><td>BMaas@ac.org</td><td>morbi tincidunt ac sollicitudin nec ac orci vitae donec non</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>8</td><td>Heidi</td><td>Rush</td><td>738</td><td>1425 Porta Rd</td><td>SD</td><td>14708</td><td>(341) 095-7183</td><td>DSchrag@sapien.net</td><td>nullam sed aliquam turpis et sagittis libero sed tellus dui</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>9</td><td>Ganesh</td><td>Comeau</td><td>385</td><td>2641 Hendrerit Dr</td><td>MT</td><td>66612</td><td>(201) 977-9765</td><td>SBurks@ipsum.ly</td><td>sit vestibulum ac pretium eget augue sit augue sagittis tellus</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>10</td><td>Regine</td><td>Marina</td><td>479</td><td>6204 Ac Rd</td><td>WI</td><td>55667</td><td>(824) 223-9924</td><td>VPeschke@pharetra.org</td><td>amet fringilla vitae tortor vestibulum egestas eget eget amet sed</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>11</td><td>Wichaya</td><td>Thomas</td><td>487</td><td>861 Risus Dr</td><td>KY</td><td>63224</td><td>(599) 823-8970</td><td>BMohamed@adipiscing.ly</td><td>placerat dolor pulvinar nec morbi amet porta sagittis lacus magna</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>12</td><td>Douglass</td><td>Holliday</td><td>488</td><td>8829 Sit Ave</td><td>IA</td><td>86970</td><td>(113) 897-8276</td><td>CLieb@convallis.io</td><td>dolor magna id amet lorem eros ipsum magna non aliquam</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>13</td><td>Prince</td><td>Schwartzberg</td><td>790</td><td>1757 Sit Ct</td><td>IL</td><td>94739</td><td>(299) 471-3039</td><td>DFavus@quis.org</td><td>magna tincidunt ipsum hendrerit ac vitae tortor consequat magna elit</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>14</td><td>Lola</td><td>Hensley</td><td>486</td><td>8159 Dui Rd</td><td>MN</td><td>88877</td><td>(788) 031-7392</td><td>MBradley@scelerisque.org</td><td>suspendisse donec placerat nec suspendisse lacus ipsum elementum at lorem</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>15</td><td>Dainius</td><td>Finn</td><td>355</td><td>6072 Massa Dr</td><td>VT</td><td>75787</td><td>(638) 345-2650</td><td>MWilcox@velit.ly</td><td>morbi pretium dui dolor elit sed non vestibulum sit dui</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>16</td><td>Aisha</td><td>Schuhmann</td><td>328</td><td>9709 Sagittis Ln</td><td>ND</td><td>44161</td><td>(147) 281-5251</td><td>GDech@mi.com</td><td>massa sed placerat libero egestas at massa sagittis libero orci</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>17</td><td>Maria</td><td>Peacock</td><td>269</td><td>2241 Amet Ave</td><td>MO</td><td>81339</td><td>(656) 079-5964</td><td>POliva@tincidunt.org</td><td>ac hendrerit molestie ipsum facilisis massa odio fringilla hendrerit neque</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>18</td><td>Otilia</td><td>Denbesten</td><td>778</td><td>1965 Nunc Ct</td><td>SC</td><td>98692</td><td>(985) 745-0452</td><td>SWieber@porttitor.net</td><td>aliquam orci odio id ac magna magna aenean sagittis lectus</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>19</td><td>Jian</td><td>Sanchez</td><td>796</td><td>6439 Sit Ln</td><td>OR</td><td>24879</td><td>(168) 754-6725</td><td>AVrtis@porttitor.net</td><td>sapien ipsum nullam pretium quis tincidunt tincidunt sit mattis porttitor</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>20</td><td>Tanny</td><td>Wieland</td><td>814</td><td>7331 Et Rd</td><td>SD</td><td>65216</td><td>(414) 322-1606</td><td>ACasariego@et.org</td><td>odio augue in id lacus tincidunt morbi tempor orci tincidunt</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>21</td><td>Alejandro</td><td>Sidaway</td><td>995</td><td>8125 Placerat Rd</td><td>VA</td><td>98301</td><td>(202) 112-1194</td><td>RHaag@nullam.ly</td><td>lacus aliquam et sagittis etiam aenean lorem ipsum non facilisis</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>22</td><td>Yolanda</td><td>Swanson</td><td>530</td><td>276 Amet Ct</td><td>VT</td><td>42999</td><td>(621) 796-4436</td><td>TDenard@lectus.gov</td><td>lacus vitae quis dui orci ipsum odio pulvinar et nunc</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>23</td><td>Azra</td><td>Filleul</td><td>443</td><td>499 Sagittis Dr</td><td>OK</td><td>59700</td><td>(485) 530-0532</td><td>LSwetland@consectetur.net</td><td>magna mattis sollicitudin placerat vel facilisis sed ac non et</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>24</td><td>Cassandra</td><td>Labrucherie</td><td>606</td><td>6849 Tellus Ct</td><td>SC</td><td>44245</td><td>(960) 044-9381</td><td>WLafave@lectus.io</td><td>ac nullam magna ante sapien tellus tincidunt eros magna sagittis</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>25</td><td>Theodore</td><td>Saver</td><td>150</td><td>5 Tincidunt Ave</td><td>IL</td><td>58210</td><td>(152) 001-4978</td><td>KTorres@sed.io</td><td>ac tincidunt nec rutrum pulvinar id aliquam placerat pharetra placerat</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>26</td><td>Susi</td><td>Murphy</td><td>900</td><td>1614 Hendrerit St</td><td>AZ</td><td>80212</td><td>(532) 030-5050</td><td>ZRingling@sit.io</td><td>quis odio et sapien sit amet eros et augue turpis</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>27</td><td>Corazon</td><td>Lawrence</td><td>577</td><td>3571 Facilisis Rd</td><td>CA</td><td>35195</td><td>(318) 200-2692</td><td>REckhart@scelerisque.io</td><td>tincidunt sit dolor mi donec magna massa vel suspendisse placerat</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>28</td><td>Khosrow</td><td>Fisher</td><td>802</td><td>4323 Tortor Ln</td><td>AK</td><td>38949</td><td>(493) 277-9670</td><td>FHarmati@magna.ly</td><td>lectus tortor ac ipsum sagittis lacus dolor ac fringilla nec</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>29</td><td>Melgema</td><td>Lopez</td><td>893</td><td>1738 Vestibulum Ln</td><td>MS</td><td>32638</td><td>(953) 255-2707</td><td>ABurgin@tortor.ly</td><td>molestie at vel at placerat pharetra consequat dolor nunc placerat</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>30</td><td>Chun</td><td>Lester</td><td>928</td><td>9681 Vestibulum Ct</td><td>ND</td><td>21333</td><td>(474) 719-0476</td><td>ETierney@pulvinar.gov</td><td>vestibulum ipsum tincidunt placerat eros turpis morbi ipsum sit malesuada</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>31</td><td>Dwayne</td><td>Balasubramanian</td><td>418</td><td>3129 Pharetra Dr</td><td>SD</td><td>57558</td><td>(457) 589-4620</td><td>ESyner@aenean.com</td><td>amet sit nec amet lectus augue consequat consectetur vel sed</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>32</td><td>Joshua</td><td>Williamson</td><td>702</td><td>6313 Vestibulum St</td><td>NJ</td><td>39057</td><td>(346) 084-7444</td><td>VFeldman@elit.ly</td><td>sit tempor at lacus libero lorem sit nullam tempor aliquam</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>33</td><td>Shawn</td><td>Dartmann</td><td>124</td><td>4892 Aliquam Rd</td><td>IA</td><td>17745</td><td>(500) 390-3779</td><td>RNesbitt@massa.net</td><td>sit sapien magna libero augue consectetur fringilla orci ac tortor</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>34</td><td>Rupa</td><td>Helgren</td><td>594</td><td>5944 Sed Ave</td><td>CO</td><td>96680</td><td>(174) 841-4348</td><td>FShebish@morbi.net</td><td>at elementum neque ac in consequat elementum magna vitae mattis</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>35</td><td>Gia</td><td>Marks</td><td>635</td><td>2519 Convallis Dr</td><td>GA</td><td>66324</td><td>(188) 657-9140</td><td>SForsyth@adipiscing.gov</td><td>pharetra pulvinar amet dui elementum suspendisse et odio tellus amet</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>36</td><td>Tyetha</td><td>Ahn</td><td>543</td><td>9900 Eros Ct</td><td>PA</td><td>53390</td><td>(482) 686-6141</td><td>LHobbs@non.io</td><td>pulvinar lorem quis fringilla eget velit sed augue rutrum augue</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>37</td><td>Gregory</td><td>Christine</td><td>527</td><td>751 Ipsum Rd</td><td>AK</td><td>44543</td><td>(258) 666-2073</td><td>HCrooker@donec.com</td><td>massa vitae dolor sollicitudin consectetur sollicitudin malesuada massa velit egestas</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>38</td><td>Yelena</td><td>Shanoski</td><td>646</td><td>1612 Donec Ave</td><td>KY</td><td>30729</td><td>(905) 301-3407</td><td>JMcmenamin@massa.gov</td><td>sapien rutrum adipiscing et sed sollicitudin vestibulum pharetra at neque</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>39</td><td>Thursday</td><td>Helm</td><td>666</td><td>5568 Nec Rd</td><td>NE</td><td>94390</td><td>(487) 403-7019</td><td>RMorin@sed.org</td><td>risus hendrerit sollicitudin vestibulum placerat lorem eros consequat lorem magna</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>40</td><td>Melinda</td><td>Oliva</td><td>525</td><td>6973 Rutrum Ct</td><td>IA</td><td>38519</td><td>(964) 234-5172</td><td>FStephens@in.com</td><td>dolor lacus nec odio in etiam facilisis lorem ipsum et</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>41</td><td>Latasha</td><td>Slocum</td><td>210</td><td>8374 Fringilla St</td><td>NV</td><td>23913</td><td>(678) 453-4263</td><td>JWelchert@id.gov</td><td>donec massa dolor elementum scelerisque risus lacus id lorem in</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>42</td><td>Kenneth</td><td>Zazzara</td><td>269</td><td>3364 Tempor Dr</td><td>MO</td><td>30642</td><td>(874) 633-3017</td><td>TGarayan@tincidunt.ly</td><td>sollicitudin nullam egestas aenean molestie velit nec sed tincidunt scelerisque</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>43</td><td>Francine</td><td>Daniels</td><td>366</td><td>2141 Amet Rd</td><td>OH</td><td>90786</td><td>(856) 781-7309</td><td>SIngham@pretium.ly</td><td>egestas amet vel ac pretium lacus nec tortor facilisis et</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>44</td><td>Marie</td><td>Krebs</td><td>124</td><td>4229 Sit Ln</td><td>DE</td><td>41786</td><td>(572) 023-1295</td><td>EClagg@curabitur.io</td><td>lacus elit sagittis quis nec vestibulum malesuada mattis morbi etiam</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>45</td><td>Stanley</td><td>Zehnacker</td><td>456</td><td>4610 Odio St</td><td>VT</td><td>70223</td><td>(257) 234-6755</td><td>HPennell@morbi.gov</td><td>vel aliquam mattis libero sed pharetra donec malesuada pharetra lectus</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>46</td><td>Furdella</td><td>Toffoli</td><td>951</td><td>8366 Placerat Rd</td><td>AZ</td><td>20381</td><td>(740) 422-8726</td><td>YEarls@morbi.net</td><td>non aliquam neque tortor egestas pulvinar tempor amet molestie lorem</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>47</td><td>Talatha</td><td>Nye</td><td>808</td><td>6884 Dolor Dr</td><td>MS</td><td>97282</td><td>(589) 157-7730</td><td>DAcosta@rutrum.gov</td><td>ipsum turpis vestibulum at convallis sit neque elementum sed adipiscing</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>48</td><td>Brent</td><td>Vollrath</td><td>479</td><td>5362 Eget Dr</td><td>MO</td><td>74989</td><td>(664) 642-4525</td><td>YMarina@sollicitudin.net</td><td>massa elementum elit pretium malesuada mi vestibulum non aliquam neque</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>49</td><td>Melissa</td><td>Quintana</td><td>405</td><td>1302 Lacus Dr</td><td>PA</td><td>38853</td><td>(354) 903-9363</td><td>AMarrinson@lacus.io</td><td>morbi quis neque placerat malesuada tincidunt morbi risus at tortor</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>50</td><td>Guadalupe</td><td>Eseltine</td><td>206</td><td>5495 Rutrum Ct</td><td>AR</td><td>37546</td><td>(540) 500-5816</td><td>TLester@morbi.com</td><td>porttitor sit massa ipsum ac massa ac hendrerit vitae malesuada</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

        </div>

        <div class="ui-layout-south no-print" style="text-align: center;">
            <span id="feedback" style="float: right;"></span>
            The footer            
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested):

```
$(function(){

    var $table = $('#fixed-columns-table'),
        scrollerHeight = $table.parent().innerHeight() - 
            $table.children('thead').outerHeight() +
            $table.children('tfoot').outerHeight();

    $('#fixed-columns-table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['scroller', 'zebra'],
        widgetOptions : {
            scroller_height : scrollerHeight,
            scroller_fixedColumns : 2
        }
    });

});
```

The code basically sets the `scroller_height` to fill the available space of the element wrapping the table.